# Why does the animation not update itself with body of View in process of an Animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am moving a Circle up and down with very simple example in down code, we can active or inactive animation for this job! the issue is here, when I want move the Circle with animation in middle of process I want cancel and kill animation but animation does not respect to change of State!!! why it is happing? how can I make animation conform and respect to State value while the animation happing!?

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var alignmentBool: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var activeAnimation: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.gray.overlay(Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center), alignment: alignmentBool ? .top : .bottom)
                .animation(!activeAnimation ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 5) : nil, value: [alignmentBool, activeAnimation])
            
            HStack {
                
                Button("Move it!") { alignmentBool.toggle() }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("active/inactive Animation") { activeAnimation.toggle() }
                
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            .font(Font.body.bold())
            .padding()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but have you tried `Animation.none` instead of `nil` within your `.animation(_:, value:)` method?

Comment: the problem is not about kind of Animation, the issue is there that animation cannot quit when start, unless I force the View to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit *animation cancelling*, but we can destroy animatable view to have desired effect:

```
Color.gray.overlay(Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center), alignment: alignmentBool ? .top : .bottom)
    .animation(!activeAnimation ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 5) : nil, value: [alignmentBool, activeAnimation])
    .id(activeAnimation)        // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestCancelAnimation.swift)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never used `.id()` modifier before. But seems it is important. Could you please tell the best use for `.id()`? where should I consider to use this modifier basically if it is possible for you?